# Code to convert sentence to ASCII doesn't work when there are space characters

Tags: java, ascii

I'd like to convert a sentence to ASCII but when the input is a sentence with spaces, the output is blank.

Code outputs the intended ASCII if it is just a single word.

Overall, the code written will receive an input from user, converts the String input, writes the converted sentence into a text file and reads from it.

```
   String sentence;
   int[] convert;
   int l;
   Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
   sentence=s.nextLine();

   l=sentence.length();
   convert = new int[l];
   for(int i=0; i<l; i++){
       convert[i]=sentence.charAt(i);
   }
   
   //Write to text file
    try{
       PrintWriter os = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("data.txt"));
       for(int i=0; i<l; i++){
         os.print(convert[i]);
        }
         os.close();
   }catch(IOException e){
         System.out.println("Problem with file output");
   }
   
   //Read from text file and print 
   int num;
   try{
       Scanner is = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("data.txt"));
       while(is.hasNextInt()){
         num= is.nextInt();
         System.out.print(num);
       }
       System.out.println("");
       is.close();
       
   }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
       System.out.println("File was not found");
   }
```

Comment: @user207421 "...when the input is a sentence with spaces, the output is blank."

Answer (score 1):

The following change in the code will print entire output:
while(is.hasNext()){System.out.println(is.next());}

Comment: This fixed the problem. Thanks!